# Does 'find -size 100k' use kilobytes or kibibytes?

Tags: find, size

I was looking through the linux manual and [on this page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find), the manual for find, specifically in the section about the test "-size", it states (erroneously) that a **kilobyte** is 1024 **bytes**. This is, as far as I learned, false. A kilobyte is **1000** bytes, and a **kibibyte** is 1024 bytes. So, what units does it *actually* use? Does it say "kilobytes" and mean  "1000 bytes", or does it mean "1024 bytes" and incorrectly wrote "kilobytes"?

Comment: A kilobyte has traditionally been 1024 bytes; the revisionism to make "kilobyte" 1000 bytes is new. There is a great deal of opposition to this change in the industry. Look into the data sheet for any memory integrated circuit, or, heck, the Intel architecture manuals.

Comment: I think that, given that [the standard came out in 1999](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/12253), has been around long enough [to be obsoleted by a new more extensive _International System of Quantities_](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/7479) (itself 10 years old now), and had been on the table for a few years before that, we don't get to use the _it's newfangled and I don't like new_ objection any more.  That's _really_ stretching the definition of "new".

Comment: Even if it's not technically correct, most people I know use kilobyte and friends in the 2^n definitions because kibi, mebi, etc. sound dumb. I have yet to find an occurrence where there's been confusion outside of hard drive sizes (and there, hard drive manufacturers don't get it right either!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well spotted! The explicit explanation is correct. 1k means kibibytes (1024 bytes). I tested it by creating a range of sizes and seeing which were identified.

```
$ for i in 999 1000 1001 1023 1024 1025; do dd if=/dev/urandom of=$i bs=1 count=$i; done
$ find . -size 1k
.
./1024
./1023
./1001
./1000
./999
```

You can see that the 1024 bytes file is found (and not the 1025 bytes file).

(You might think of filing a bug report, if you like.)

Comment: The problem has been solved in several versions of find.

Comment: [The `findutils` package's doco was fixed in 2017.](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/commit/doc/find.texi?id=79bc9191c75087abc85c2c49827c34023890aa7d)

Comment: It's not fixed in the latest stable version of findutils (4.6.0), which was released over two years ago.

Comment: Distributions have not been using 4.6.0 for almost as long.  Debian+Ubuntu have been using later versions since 2016, for examples, and both Debian 10 (in testing) and.Ubuntu 17.10.1 (released) already have the doco fix.

Comment: @JdeBP Oh right. I'm on Arch, which is using 4.6.0, and I normally presume that it's using versions that are no older then Debian/Ubuntu. Interesting that they've both shipped the unstable versions!

Comment: +1 Still true for `bash` v5.0 on both Arch and Android as of today. The `-size` flag assumes kibibytes.

Answer (score 3):

The manual on [the page you link](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) is outdated and incorrect. 
One [on line page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) where this error has been already corrected is:

> -size n[cwbkMG]
>   File uses n units of space, rounding up. The following suffixes can be used:
>   `b'    for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is used)
>   `c'    for bytes
>   `w'    for two-byte words
>   `k'    for Kibibytes (KiB, units of 1024 bytes)
>   `M'    for Mebibytes (MiB, units of 1024 * 1024 = 1048576 bytes)
>   `G'    for Gibibytes (GiB, units of 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 1073741824 bytes)

The [BSD find manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)) is still incorrect.

The most up-to-date manual is the `man find` in an updated OS.
From a GNU find version (find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git) the manual goes as:

> -size n[cwbkMG]
>   File uses n units of space, rounding up. The following suffixes can be used:
>
> `b'    for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is used)
>   `c'    for bytes
>   `w'    for two-byte words
>   `k'    for Kibibytes (KiB, units of 1024 bytes)
>   `M'    for Mebibytes (MiB, units of 1024 * 1024 = 1048576 bytes)
>   `G'    for Gibibytes (GiB, units of 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 1073741824 bytes)

So, the problem has been solved already in some versions of find.

Comment: There s no "error". The document defines what "kilobyte" means and the resulting description is consistent with the behavior of the software. (That definition happens to match the traditional one that was actually enshrined in IEEE POSIX documents at one point.)

Comment: And, for that matter, why is it not an "error" in this revised page that the suffix "k" is used for "kibibytes"? Isn't that letter an S.I. unit prefix meaning 1000?

Comment: Talking to the OP and therefore using the OP description of error: *it states (erroneously) that a kilobyte is 1024 bytes.*. What you choose to call correct or incorrect depends on your opinion. @Kaz

Comment: As for my *opinion*: I learned long ago (in electronics) that a `k` meant 1024 bits. And that `k` meant 1000 in science (physics). I always found funny that the same prefix had two meanings. In present days, binary prefixes are being called `i`, so 1024 would be `KiBytes`. I find that an improvement and have gladly got used to accept it to avoid confusion. Exactly as the OP is being confused right now.

Comment: Umm, no it doesn't. What is correct or incorrect is a matter of consistency between what is described and the description. If the document says that a kilobyte is 768 bytes, and that's how it's used in the program, then the document is correct. OP is confused because he doesn't accept the definitions of terms given in a document.

Comment: Very little confusion existed in this matter before this whole moronic kibibyte business. A kilobyte was 1024 and so on. Only if you were buying a hard disk did you have to accept that a megabyte is a million. After you hooked that drive up and formatted a filesystem, a megabyte became 1024  * 1024 again and all was well.  It's the rude redefinition that is being foisted upon us that is the root cause of the confusion.

Comment: Hmmm. The document is **consistent**. It does what it says it is going to do. Whether correct or not depends on what is generally accepted as the correct meaning of the `k`. Which, as I said, is already different in different fields of human knowledge. @Kaz

Comment: The confusion is clear and persistent. A **kilo**gram is one Kg and means only 1000 grams. A **kilo**meter is 1000 meters. Only in some areas of human knowledge (mainly electronics) is common to see **kilo** used as 1024. It seems rational to me to use two names for two meanings: k for 1000 and ki for 1024. Yes, it will take some years for everyone to get there: have a happy journey @Kaz .

Comment: +1 good investigative work. FWIW the latest stable version of findutils is 4.6.0, which still contains this "feature". It was released over two years ago. And the previous version was released 6.5 years before that. So it may be a while before it's fixed in the stable version.

Comment: @isaac Yes, and now, thanks to this redefinition effort, it is common in **exactly that same area of knowledge** to use "kilo" as 1000 **and** 1024.

Comment: @Kaz I have been in electronics for a long time, the dual use has been present for a long time. It always has been the custom to understand a kiloWatt as 1000 Watt. Nobody thinks of 1024 Watts. But it **was** custom to understand a kilobit as 1024 bits. Now that is being called a "binary kilobit" or a kibit. It seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Please file a bug at [the FreeBSD bugzilla](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/), preferably with a suitable patch to [the source](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.bin/find/find.1?view=markup#l822) attached.

Comment: @JdeBP The document clearly defines its terms starting at [line 824](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.bin/find/find.1?view=markup#l824). These match the behavior of the program. **There is no bug, except if you're under 25, and your babysitter's names were Google and Wikipedia.** OMG, someone on the internet is using "kilo" wrong: bring in the helicopters.